# Pourquoi utilise-t-on « faire partager » plutôt que « partager » ?

Tags: sens, usage, constructions-causatives

Serait-ce un mal de « partager » volontairement et en quelque sorte en prendre une certaine responsabilité plutôt que de « faire partager » par quelqu’autre entité que soi-même ?

Pourquoi partout j’entends plus souvent « Je vais vous faire partager cette information » (bien que malheureusement cela ne soit plus une référence pour l'usage de la langue, je l'entends souvent dire à la télé, au JT notamment) plutôt que « Je partage cette information avec vous » ?

J'entends souvent la forme « faire partager » plutôt que « partager ». Il y a à mon sens un non-sens, justement, dans la plupart des cas où on utilise « faire partager ».
Serait-ce un problème de génération, celui qui ne veut plus rien assumer ? Une forme plutôt qu'une autre… est-ce une question de philosophie ou de bon usage de la langue… française en l’occurrence.

Un exemple : je cherche « faire partager » et le moteur de recherche me donne [cet article](http://www.onisep.fr/Decouvrir-les-metiers/Des-metiers-selon-mes-gouts/J-ai-le-sens-du-contact/Je-veux-faire-partager-ma-passion) ; il me semble ici que cette personne partage sa passion et que *faire partager* n'a pas de sens.
Cela me rappelle ma plus tendre enfance où on me disait assez souvent qu'il fallait utiliser *partager* plutôt que *faire partager*.

---

Je ne sais pas trop vers qui me tourner pour poser cette question. Suis-je au bon endroit pour poser cette question ?

Comment: En effet, c'est bien une question de langue même si elle se fonde sur une autre question sous-jacente, plus large, sur le plan philosophique/politique. Question intéressante, d'ailleurs.

Comment: Merci @Stéphane pour la correction... orthographique surtout !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trésor de la Langue française, article partager.

> **Partager** :
>   2. Prendre part à; posséder en commun avec quelqu'un. Partager le repas de qqn; partager la chambre, le lit, le logement de qqn;
>   partager les soucis, le succès, le sort, la vie de qqn.

-

> ♦ **Faire partager**. Communiquer:
>   5. ... ma mère me permettait volontiers de passer des heures entières chez ce charmant enfant, auquel je fis bientôt partager mon goût pour
>   les vers que j'admirais si vivement... (Bourget.)

**Partager** un goût,  c'est avoir un goût en commun avec quelqu'un.
C'est un état de fait et non une action. Ce n'est pas une action volontaire.
Au début, seul Bourget avait le goût des vers.
Il a **fait partager** ce goût à l'enfant. Action de Bourget allant vers  l'enfant.
Il n'y a aucune délégation de responsabilité à une autre entité. C'est au contraire une action volontaire dirigée vers autrui, ouverte... 
Et maintenant, Bourget et l'enfant **partagent** ce goût, ils l'ont en commun.

Je reporte ici une réponse d'un autre forum qui me convient mieux.

Lire ici pour la réponse originale : http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic38383-pourquoi-utiliseton-faire-partager-plutot-que-partager.html

Comment: Très bien expliqué. Dans ce sens *Partager* est bien un état, alors que l'action, c'est *faire partager*.

Answer (score 6):

La [banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=partager&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) de l'Office québécois de la langue française indique :

> *Partager* n’a pas le sens de « communiquer », sens que l’on recense parfois maintenant pour le verbe anglais *to share*. On emploiera plutôt en français des verbes comme *exprimer*, *émettre*, *raconter*, *communiquer*, *faire part de*, selon le contexte, ou encore ***faire partager***.

Pour aller dans ton sens, il me semble que oui, *partager* peut paraître plus autoritaire que *faire partager*. Si je *partage* un gâteau, je t'en donne une part (« unilatéralement »), alors que si je te *fais partager* mon repas, tu me sembles plus invité à te servir, et à participer de toi-même. Un peu.

Sinon, il peut y avoir une simple différence sémantique : je *fais partager* une information si j'introduis la personne qui va effectivement la partager avec mon auditoire (je *lui* fais la partager).

En tout cas, trop d'autres explications me semblent raisonnables pour en venir à accuser toute une génération.

Comment: "partager peut paraître plus autoritaire que partager" voudrais-tu dire "partager peut paraître plus autoritaire que faire partager" ?

Comment: Bien sûr, oui, merci :)

Comment: Si je prend ton exemple. Il me semble que l'on ne peut que partager un repas avec quelqu'un et non faire partager. J'ai l'impression que "faire partager un repas" est comme l'expression "faire faire", soit faire faire quelque chose à quelqu'un... quelqu'un d'autre que soit-même. J'imagine que l'on peut débattre sans fin, je ne pousserai donc pas le bouchon plus loin. :o)

Comment: Précisément, si je fais partager mon repas par mon invité (« hôte », aussi, mais c'est suffisament ambiguë comme ça) (je *lui fais partager*, donc), ça l'invite plus que si c'était moi qui partageais :)

Answer (score 0):

Partager c'est offrir la connaissance à l'autre ! "
Faire partager" qui n'a jamais existé durant des siècles... me semble vouloir dire que tu vas obliger  quelqu'un a partager ce qu'il possède... Cette expression me rend fou... Elle ne veux rien dire !
C'est comme si on disait, "je vais te faire manger"  au lieu de : " je vais manger avec toi.." . Ça ne veux rien dire.
C'est comme "très",  qui est remplacé sans cesse par "trop" , ou quand on entend à la télé sur: " C'est des bateaux anciens..."  plutôt  que "Ce sont..." Quel honte pour la France.

Comment: Personnellement, j'aurai dit : « **Quelle** honte ... »

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE. *"Faire partager" qui n'a jamais existé durant des siècles* avez-vous une source pour étayer ce point de vue ou bien souhaitez-vous juste nous faire partager un billet d'humeur? De plus, ça ne répond pas vraiment à la question posée

Comment: @toto Moi aussi, mais j'aurais écrit *j'aurais dit* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre: Effectivement, la touche S de mon clavier doit être en panne ... ;-)

Comment: @toto C'et ûrement ça !