# How would you say “business”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Business could be used in many ways. In my case, I would like to know how to say

- Review this business
- You have reviewed this bussiness before

So just like Yelp where they have all local businesses to review.

Just don't tell me it's enterprise cause it's not.

Comment: Why do you say it's not *entreprise*?

Comment: I am not really sure, but it sounds hard to call a small business an enterprise.

Comment: @Rocks There is no minimum size for an *entreprise*. A person working on their own is an *auto-entreprise*.

Comment: [Aussi](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=505149), _petite et/ou moyenne entreprise_, _très petite entreprise_, _micro-entreprise_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using *entreprise* has the advantage of not being specific. If you're still reluctant to use it, you could go for *magasin* or *commerce* (used by Yelp) for retail-oriented businesses.

Comment: You have identified that _Yelp_ uses the word "commerce" for business; see also [this](http://www.yelp.fr/guidelines) - I note they chose the "avis" for "review" and have an "écrire un avis" button.

Answer (score 13):

When you're talking about a specific business establishment, as opposed to the company in general, the usual term would be ***établissement***.

> You have already posted a review of this business.
>   Vous avez déjà posté une critique de cet établissement.

When the business is a shop, it would be more common to use the word *commerce*.

If you mean the company in general, then *société* is probably the right word (but it depends on the context).

There is no minimum size for an *entreprise*, but it tends to refer more to the business administration side of things than on the retail customer's view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, I disagree with the translation.

The translation for "business" is "affaire".
"To do some business" translates as "faire des affaires".
"A business" is "une affaire"

"Entreprise" is the french for "company".

"Établissement" would translate as "institution" in English.

In English, a business can equally refer to a fortune 500 company and the local bakery. "Un commerce" sounds a bit inappropriate when referring to a fortune 500 company. It sounds more appropriate if referring to a small local business.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've got against *entreprise*, but since you don’t want to use it alone, then you probably wouldn’t want “une entreprise commerciale” either.

As Alexandre has already mentioned, “[un commerce](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/fr/en/search?q=commerce&lang=en&m=click)” is a great alternative, and if for whatever reason you might not like that excellent answer,

> “[une firme](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/fr/en/translate/firme?l=en%7Cfr&lang=en)”

could also work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply "société". This is the official french word used for any company in France. You find this word in many kind of incorporation names like "Société Anonyme", "Société à Responsabilité Limitée" ...

Answer (score 1):

"L'[*entreprise*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=500984)" (also [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entreprise)) and its synonyms are useful, but *reviewing* a business in the context you describe is quite different from reviewing it in the context of *due diligence*. The "business" we're reviewing here is really what caters to the need(s) and/or desire(s) of the customers, the "business" of this business: its *product*. It's not really important whether this is about retail, entertainment, educational, or professional services, or whether it's a shop, boutique, salon, stand, counter, office, cinema, moving vehicle etc. - it's the place we go to, the food we eat, the service quality or what's inside the box we're reviewing. And products can [include](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8429549) services as well. Furthermore, one can [*share*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4391) the experience they had of the product:

> *Faire part de son expérience du produit.*
>
> *Vous avez déjà fait part de votre expérience du produit.*

In the context of a specific entry, it's arguable one could even let go of the "du produit" part and keep the focus on the experience; not unlike how *Yelp* settled for the user facing "*écrire un avis*" and never really specifies it's about what as the function of this is quite obvious in context.