# Pourquoi les youtubeurs disent-ils "je vais vous partager..." ?

Tags: usage, verbes, verbes-pronominaux, pronoms-personnels

Pourquoi les youtubeurs disent-ils "je vais vous partager quelque chose" au lieu de dire "je vais partager quelque chose avec vous" ?

Bien que le sens soit proche de "je vais vous **donner** quelque chose", lorsque on me dit "je vais vous partager quelque chose" j'ai l'impression que c'est moi qu'on va partager, qu'on va me couper en part comme un gâteau.

Ai-je raison de m'offusquer ?
Si oui à quoi est dû ce changement de langage ?

P.S. j'ai vu cette autre question dont l'interrogation n'est pas la même [Pourquoi utilise-t-on « faire partager » plutôt que « partager » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-faire-partager-plut%c3%b4t-que-partager/4392#4392)

Comment: par ignardise? :) [mot inventé]

Answer (score 5):

C'est une évolution comme il y en a toujours eu et comme il y en aura toujours.

Ici, l'objectif est clairement la simplification. Le risque de confusion avec un partage physique de la personne elle-même est quand même bien réduit.

On retrouve exactement le même phénomène avec :

> Je vais me marier avec toi.

qui devient parfois :

> Je vais te marier.

Inutile de s'offusquer, ça n'a de toute façon jamais vraiment d'effet sur les évolutions des langues que l'on appelle justement pour ça, des langues vivantes. Seul l'avenir nous dira s'il s'agit d'une mode ou de quelque chose de plus persistant.

Comment: Penses-tu que la simplification peut aussi s'appliquer à _faire partager_ : _Le conférencier voulait nous (faire) partager son expérience de coopération internationale._

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Oui, bien sûr. *Je veux vous partager mon expérience* et *le conférencier veut nous partager son expérience* sont de la même veine.

Comment: https://travauxdeplume.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/vous-partager-ou-partager-avec-vous%C2%A0/

Comment: @None Oui, on trouve dans des commentaires de 2019: *La langue évolue. L’avenir le dira…*

Answer (score 0):

Oui, tu as bien raison de t'offusquer car la phrase est incorrecte, (tout comme l'adjectif déceptif que les youtubeuses emploient comme synonyme de décevant). On partage quelque chose à quelqu'un, donc le "avec" est obligatoire. Le langage évolue dans le temps, c'est un fait mais l'argument de la simplification ne permet pas de dire n'importe quoi. Et puis pourquoi toujours se laisser glisser sur la pente de la facilité ? On pourrait aussi essayer d'enrichir notre langue, ou alors il ne faut pas nous étonner de la baisse du niveau général de la population française.

Answer (score 0):

C'est tout simplement un anglicisme!
Emploi déconseillé de partager

L’emploi du verbe partager, au sens de « communiquer », est déconseillé. Il est calqué sur l’anglais to share et est critiqué dans plusieurs ouvrages de référence. Pour rendre cette idée, on recourra plutôt à des verbes qui apportent davantage de nuance et de précision, comme exprimer, émettre, raconter, communiquer, faire part de, selon le contexte, ou encore faire partager.

Exemples :

- Elle a raconté ses aventures aux autres participants. (et non : a partagé ses aventures)
- Les dernières consignes nous avaient été transmises lors de la réunion précédente. (et non : nous avaient été partagées)
- Le conférencier voulait nous faire partager son expérience de coopération internationale. (et non : voulait nous partager son expérience)
- Le journal communiquera les derniers renseignements sur l’affaire. (et non : partagera les derniers renseignements)

Comment: En quoi est-ce un anglicisme? En anglais on dit *I'm going to share this with you*, *share* n'appelle pas non plus un COD qui soit une personne.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Je vais vous partager quelque chose.

Le *vous* a ici une fonction de complément d'objet indirect.
Or d'après le site du CNRTL, *partager* ne s'emploie pas avec un tel complément; nous pouvons en déduire est que l'usage est bel et bien nouveau.

Quant à ce qu'il veut dire, je me laisse aller à une supposition.
Si le vidéaste avait dit "Je vais partager quelque chose avec vous", il aurait sous-entendu qu'il en garderait une partie.
Alors qu'ici, il fait un don, à une communauté dont les membres se partageront l'objet entre eux. Une façon, plus classique peut-être mais sans doute moins élégante, de ce dire serait ainsi "Je vais partager quelque chose entre vous".

Comment: Il en garde forcément une partie puisqu'il s'agit d'information.

Comment: Mais justement ils font comme si ce n'était pas le cas, c'est une sorte d'hyperbole en somme. Encore une fois c'est juste une hypothèse.