# « Je lui ai fait partager son cadeau avec les autres » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes, locutions

> Je lui ai fait [partager](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/partager) son cadeau avec les autres.

Dit le parent d'un enfant. Évidemment, il ne s'agit pas de [communiquer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6205/26366) mais plutôt de *faire donner une partie de*,  car il ne s'agit pas du syntagme « faire partager » et on a un objet concret...

A-t-on une quelconque difficulté à comprendre ce dont il s'agit ici (vu l'air du temps, davantage de partage dématérialisé que concret, d'autres sens du verbe etc.) ? Quel synonyme de *faire* peut-on employer en contexte pour introduire *partager* tout en évitant la cooccurrence ?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la question. La phrase est parfaitement compréhensible, idiomatique, et pas ambiguë. Quel est le problème ? Tu sembles craindre une confusion, mais je ne vois pas avec quoi.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' C'était à force de lire des trucs sur les youtubers qui vous partagent de quoi puis la question liée sur faire partager, j'ai eu un doute, une inquiétude sur le fait qu'on comprenne encore des trucs concrets. Ça aurait pu être sur cosette. Je suis un peu supris que ce soit à +3.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Pourquoi ne pas dire "Je l'ai fait partager son cadeau avec les autres" ? Après tout, on dit "J'ai fait *quelqu'un* partager son cadeau" et non "J'ai fait partager *à quelqu'un* son cadeau", non ?

Comment: @cadaniluk Non, grammaticalement ça serait « J'ai fait partager son cadeau à l'enfant », mais on n'utilise pas souvent ce sens de *faire* quand la personne n'est pas un pronom, on dirait plutôt « j'ai obligé l'enfant à partager son cadeau ».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La phrase est facilement compréhensible.

On pourrait remplacer *faire* par d'autres verbes, plus courants ici, même s'ils ne sont pas vraiment synonymes :

> Je lui ai dit de partager son cadeau avec les autres.

> Je lui ai demandé de partager son cadeau avec les autres.